# Local template temp variable within ngFor loop in Angular2

Tags: angular

Within a for loop in a template, I want to have some `editable` toggle flag to show and hide stuff which each iterated item. The item could be a row for example.

I just couldn't figure out how to create a local variable easily. I don't want to create a component for each row or some directive. Because in Angular1, you can just `ng-init="editable=false"`, and somewhere within the child dom, you can just toggle is by `editable=!editable` and this is in the scope of this particular child which all makes sense.

Please help me improve this, currently this will toggle all the rows. I need to have local variable for each row.

```
<div *ngFor="let c of comments">
  <button (click)="editable=!editable">edit</button>
  <p *ngIf="editable"><textarea>{{c.message}}</textarea></p>
</div>
```

How to do this in angular2~4?

Comment: Why not just make "editable" a property of each "comment"? Even if the data needs to go elsewhere it's pretty trivial to strip out or add in the property as required.

Answer (score 4):

```
<div *ngFor="let c of comments;let i=index">
  <button (click)="toggleEditable(i)">edit</button>
  <p *ngIf="editable[i]"><textarea>{{c.message}}</textarea></p>
</div>
```

```
editable = [true, false, true];

toggleEditable(idx) {
  this.editable[idx] = !this.editable[idx];
}
```

`editable` needs to have the same number of values as `comments`.